# differentiating primary tile vs app-list wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an app for WP8.I want to know how to find out that my app is coming to foreground by clicking on the App-list or primary tile which user created.In a way I want to know how many users creates primary tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a navigation parameter to your secondary tile like this :

```
        string tileParameter = "Param=myParameter"; 
        ShellTile tile = CheckIfTileExist(tileParameter); 
        if (tile == null) 
        { 
            StandardTileData secondaryTile = new StandardTileData 
            { 
                Title = tileParameter, 
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("Background-Secondary.png", UriKind.Relative), 
                Count = 2, 
                BackContent = "Secondary Tile Test" 

            }; 
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + tileParameter, UriKind.Relative), secondaryTile); 
        }
```

and then, in your MainPage's OnNavigatedTo event, you can get this parameter with something like this:

```
        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Param")) 
        { 
            string param = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["Param"];//Get "Param" this query string. 
            //Do whatever you want with this parameter
        }
```

Comment: C Is there a way i can know that my app is launched from app-list or Primary Tile.

Comment: No, I'm afraid there's no way to know that. However, if you set a parameter to you second live tiles, you can infer that if your app is launched without parameter, it is launched from the app list or primary tile.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a query string in your URI? If so you can check the NavigationContext.QueryString and see if the parameter used from your secondary tile is set or not.

Comment: Is there a way i can know that my app is launched from app-list or Primary Tile